# Smooth scrolling of expandablelistview containing listviews

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

My app has a screen with an expandablelistview. Within the expandablelistview are collapsible rows that contain listviews. These listviews contain a dynamic number of items and with dynamic heights on each item. As listviews are meant to be set to a hard-coded height and then to have scrolling within them, and I don't want to have scrolling within scrolling, I've had to get around that by calculating the actual height of the listview's items then set the height of the listview to that height so that all of its contents will fit within the exandablelistview row.

Here is my extension method that calculates the listview's height:

```
public static void SetHeightBasedOnChildren(this ListView listView) {
            var listAdapter = listView.Adapter;

            var totalHeight = listView.PaddingTop + listView.PaddingBottom;
            if (listView.DividerHeight > 0)
                totalHeight += (listView.DividerHeight * (listAdapter.Count - 1));

            var desiredWidth = DeviceHelper.GetDimensions ().X;// Add parameter if listview doesn't always span entire width of screen
            var listViewWidth = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec (desiredWidth, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);
            View listItem;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.Count; i++) {
                listItem = listAdapter.GetView (i, null, listView);
                if (listItem is ViewGroup && listItem.LayoutParameters == null)
                    listItem.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                listItem.Measure (listViewWidth, (int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
                totalHeight += listItem.MeasuredHeight;
            }

            var layoutParams = listView.LayoutParameters;
            layoutParams.Height = totalHeight;
            listView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        }
```

The issue with this is that when scrolling down the screen and reaching each listview, as it calculates the dynamic height of the listview's items and sets its height to that, it causes the scrolling to get really choppy.

As I mentioned that listviews are meant to be a hard-coded height, I tried swapping out our listviews for linearlayouts with vertical orientation, which are meant to have an adjustable height that fit their content so don't need any fancy height calculations on the fly. Unfortunately this approach didn't work, as linearlayouts don't cache their rows like listviews do, so the screen was completely unusable from trying to manage hundreds -> thousands of rows without any sort of caching. Note: the linearlayouts performed fine on the emulator but not on devices.

I'm wondering if anyone has ideas of how to get smooth scrolling in this situation. Some ideas I had...

1. Keep using listviews but set a hard-coded height on each item in the listview. Then I can calculate the height of the listview much faster, as I know the height based on the total number of rows. I would still have to set the height on each listview though, which makes it still not smooth but better than before. The downside is that I'd either need to make all rows tall enough to fit longer content (waste of vertical space), or truncate content that doesn't fit.
2. Look into if anyone has developed a hybrid widget, that is a linearlayout with vertical orientation that utilizes row caching.
3. Figure out how to force the expandablelistview to load the listview sections immediately on screen load rather than waiting until they're just about to come into view. The downside is we're holding a lot more in memory so this might render the screen unusable.

Thoughts??

EDIT: I should probably mention that the listviews are also within viewpagers, as the user can swipe between lists from different years (think tax records or mortgage records for a property). I bring this up so someone won't say, just don't have listviews at all, just only use the expandablelistview.

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge ? The result will be one `ListView` filled by multiple `ListAdapters`. It seems as the right-er way to do it.

Comment: Question #1: Would the "spinner adapter" it talks about be like using the viewpager control to swipe left/right between records? Question #2: Wouldn't I lose the expandablelistview's ability to expand/collapse the lists?

Comment: What's the point of having `ListView`s inside `ExpandableListView`? Why not to implement `ExpandableListAdapter` properly (e.g [getChildrenCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildrenCount(int)))

Comment: See the bottom of my question, the listviews are within viewpagers so can't be rows directly within expandablelistview.

Comment: Did you try to disable scrolling and setting height to `WRAP_CONTENT` on the inner `ListView`? I think it's what [WakelockDetector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) does.